# Set a lower bound for gdal_contour

Tags: gdal, gdal-contour

```
gdal_contour -off 1000 -i 1000
```

still creates contours at 0.

How can I let gdal_contour create contours at a given interval (e.g. 1000) but not including 0?

Answer (score 2):

You could (manually) specify the output intervals with the `-fl` argument:

```
gdal_contour -a elev -fl 1000 2000 input.tif output.shp
```

Or you could pass the output to `ogr2ogr` and use a where clause to get rid of the 0s before writing out to your final dataset:

```
gdal_contour -f geojson -a elev -i 1000 -off 1000 input.tif /vsistdout/ | ogr2ogr -where "elev != 0" output.shp /vsistdin/
```

Note the 2nd example writes a streamable format (geojson) to [`/vsistdout/`](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsistdout-standard-output-streaming), pipes that to [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) which reads the piped geojson from [`/vsistdin/`](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsistdin-standard-input-streaming).

Comment: thanks, very helpful. Especially the second approach I wasn't aware of.